# How do I create a black and white theme with Angular Material Design?

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I am looking to create a simple black and white theme for Angular Material Design. The documentation is sparse in this area.

My goal is to do this:

1. Unaccented background color is white
2. Unaccented text color is black
3. Accents, error, warning colors to be decided later

I was hoping to do something like this in a config block:

```
$mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
  .primaryPalette('black')
  .backgroundPalette('white');
```

But, the white and black palettes do not exist.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe what you will need to do is create the palettes for both black and white. For example:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial'])
.config(function($mdThemingProvider) {
  $mdThemingProvider.definePalette('black', {
    '50': '000000',
    '100': '000000',
    '200': '000000',
    '300': '000000',
    '400': '000000',
    '500': '000000',
    '600': '000000',
    '700': '000000',
    '800': '000000',
    '900': '000000',
    'A100': '000000',
    'A200': '000000',
    'A400': '000000',
    'A700': '000000',
    'contrastDefaultColor': 'light'
  });
  $mdThemingProvider.definePalette('white', {
    '50': 'ffffff',
    '100': 'ffffff',
    '200': 'ffffff',
    '300': 'ffffff',
    '400': 'ffffff',
    '500': 'ffffff',
    '600': 'ffffff',
    '700': 'ffffff',
    '800': 'ffffff',
    '900': 'ffffff',
    'A100': 'ffffff',
    'A200': 'ffffff',
    'A400': 'ffffff',
    'A700': 'ffffff',
    'contrastDefaultColor': 'dark'
  });

  $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
    .primaryPalette('black')
    .backgroundPalette('white');
});
```

Naturally, you can flesh out the rest of each palette. Of note here is that the 'contrastDefaultColor' is important to get the text color right in each case. Also, unfortunately it does seem that you need to define the whole color palette. Another option if you don't want to create entirely new palettes is to extend an existing palette:

```
var blackPalette = $mdThemingProvider.extendPalette('grey', { '500': '000000' });
$mdThemingProvider.definePalette('black', blackPalette);
```

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/Theming/03_configuring_a_theme

Comment: Thanks. This roughly works. Some things I am still unsure of. What do the theme keys mean? I recognize that they correspond to `md-hue-1`, `md-hue-2`, but that doesn't explain why those keys are used. Wouldn't using `md-hue-x` be clearer than using `A700`, etc? Also, I'm still unclear as to which hues are used when. If my css never explicitly uses any `md-hue-*` classes, which hues are being used?

Comment: The md-hue-* keys are for setting color variations (such as A700) that can be used by adding the .md-hue-* class, for example `.md-primary .md-hue-1` would use the hue specified for md-hue-1 in the primary palette. According to the docs, the default hue settings are: 500, 300, 800, A100 for primary and warn (so 500 by default, then md-hue-1 is 300, etc). So it adds a level of indirection so that the same palette could be used differently in multiple themes without adjusting the palette itself.

Comment: This all makes sense. It seems to me that this API targets the power user with complex use cases over the basic user. At the very least, more explicit documentation with more examples would help. I'll award you the bounty, but need to wait 12 hours.

Answer (score 0):

This code may help for using white and black colors in md-colors

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <!-- Angular Material style sheet -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.css">
        </head>
        <body ng-app="BlankApp" ng-cloak md-colors="::{'background': 'grey-400'}">
            <!--Your HTML content here-->
            <div flex layout="row">
                <div flex layout="row" layout-padding md-colors="{'color':'white-50', 'background': 'black-500'}"
                layout-align="center center">White text and Black background</div>
                <div flex layout="row" layout-padding md-colors="{'color':'black-50', 'background': 'white-500'}"
                layout-align="center center">Black text and White background</div>
            </div>
            <!--Your HTML content here-->
            <!-- Angular Material requires Angular.js Libraries -->
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
            <!-- Angular Material Library -->
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
            <!-- Your application bootstrap  -->
            <script>
                /**
                 * You must include the dependency on 'ngMaterial' 
                 */
                var app = angular.module('BlankApp', ['ngMaterial']);
                app.config(function($mdThemingProvider) {
                    $mdThemingProvider.definePalette('black', {
                    '50': '000000',
                    '100': '000000',
                    '200': '000000',
                    '300': '000000',
                    '400': '000000',
                    '500': '000000',
                    '600': '000000',
                    '700': '000000',
                    '800': '000000',
                    '900': '000000',
                    'A100': '000000',
                    'A200': '000000',
                    'A400': '000000',
                    'A700': '000000',
                    'contrastDefaultColor': 'light'
                    });
                    $mdThemingProvider.definePalette('white', {
                    '50': 'ffffff',
                    '100': 'ffffff',
                    '200': 'ffffff',
                    '300': 'ffffff',
                    '400': 'ffffff',
                    '500': 'ffffff',
                    '600': 'ffffff',
                    '700': 'ffffff',
                    '800': 'ffffff',
                    '900': 'ffffff',
                    'A100': 'ffffff',
                    'A200': 'ffffff',
                    'A400': 'ffffff',
                    'A700': 'ffffff',
                    'contrastDefaultColor': 'dark'
                    });

                    $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
                    .primaryPalette('black')
                    .backgroundPalette('white');
                });
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For black:

```css
$custom-primary: mat-palette($mat-grey, 900, 900, 900);
```